# Output of pv on docker-compose startup not working as expected

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, mariadb, pv

I am trying to output the progress of an import of an `.sql` file inside a mariadb docker container.

I have the following file/directory setup:

```
│-  docker-compose.yml
│-  Dockerfile
│-  import.sh
└── sql
    -  test.sql (rather big: ~ 1GB)
```

My `docker-compose.yml` is as simple as...

```yaml
services:
  db:
    build: ./
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

...with the following Dockerfile to install `pv` (pipe viewer). [`pv` should give me](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/28646/224505) a progress bar how far the import is currently...

```
FROM mariadb
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y pv
```

The `import.sh` will be executed through the mapped volume in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` [as described here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/).

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# create db
mysql -uroot -proot <<-EOF
  CREATE DATABASE test;
EOF
# import sql file and output progress with pv
echo "importing test.sql..."
pv --force "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/sql/test.sql" | mysql -uroot -proot "test"
```

---

Now, if I run `docker-compose up` it **only outputs the `100%` pv output at the end of the import**:

```
importing test.sql...
953MiB 0:01:24 [11.2MiB/s] [================================>] 100%    0:05:42
```

If I execute the same command *inside* the container it works and it gives me a moving progress bar:

```sh
pv --force "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/sql/test.sql" | mysql -uroot -proot "test"
60.4MiB 0:00:14 [5.79MiB/s] [=>                              ]  6%     0:04:53
```

How can I get this progress bar on `docker-compose up` instead of the loong wait and the `100%` output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Background

First let's understand how `pv` is able to render a moving progress bar on a text-only output to the terminal: `pv` actually just prints plain text to its stdout with each progress update:

```
"[==>           ] 25%\r"
"[======>       ] 50%\r"
"[=========>    ] 76%\r"
"[============>] 100%\n"
```

Each line here represents a single progress update for which `pv` outputs the text **within** the quotes (so no quotes).

But this will not print in multiple lines to the terminal: `\r` is a [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) character which will move the cursor back to the beginning of the line *without starting a new line*. So the next progress output will *override* the previous text resulting in the progress bar animation.

Only after the last update `pv` will print the new line character `\n` resulting in a final line break after the output.

Now to the problem with `docker-compose`: starting an app with `docker-compose up` will start all services, attach to their output and log it to its own output - prefixed with the respective service name:

```
app_1  | starting App...
db_1   | initializing database
....
```

To do this `docker-compose` will read each output line from each container and prefix it with the service name before printing it.

But as we saw before `pv` actually only prints a single line! This is why `docker-compose` will buffer the output until the end before finally printing it!

---

### Solutions

I see two possible solutions here:

1. use `docker-compose run db` to initialize the database: this will run the container with its output directly attached to the console and print the output without any buffering or post-processing.

In this case you then can even omit the `--force` flag.

2. replace `\r` with `\n` to force every progress update to be printed on a new line, e.g. using [`tr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr). Additionally to be sure to disable any output buffering you may use [`stdbuf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) with it (see [*turn off buffering in pipe*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)):

```sh
(pv --force -p "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/sql/test.sql" | mysql -uroot -proot "test") 2>&1 | stdbuf -o0 tr '\r' '\n'
```

will log

```
db_1   | [==>           ] 25%
db_1   | [======>       ] 50%
db_1   | [=========>    ] 76%
db_1   | [============>] 100%
```

---

#### Demo

Here is a small demo of the above:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM alpine
RUN apk add pv
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: sh -c "pv --force -p -Ss 1024 -L 100 /dev/urandom 2>&1 > /dev/null | tr '\r' '\n'"
```

#### Addendum

As per comments the above demo does not work with an ubuntu based image. It seems in such images `tr` will buffer its output and only print everything once it exits.

The output buffer can however be disabled using [`stdbuf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html) (see also [*turn off buffering in pipe*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)):

```
# Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y pv
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: sh -c "pv --force -p -Ss 1024 -L 100 /dev/urandom 2>&1 > /dev/null | stdbuf -o0 tr '\r' '\n'"
```

Comment: Sadly your solution No. 2 doesn't work. I still needed the `--force` parameter so it would output anything... And even with that it only shows all the progress output **at the end** of the import. Does that maybe have something to do that I am using windows as my docker host system? Same behaviour if I use WSL2 or hyper-v docker engine.

Comment: Yes, dropping `--force` is only for the first solution, the second will still need it.
But that's odd: I verified the solution with `command: sh -c "pv --force -p -Ss 1024 -L 100 /dev/urandom 2>&1 > /dev/null | tr '\r' '\n'"` in the `docker-compose.yml` and it worked as described. Be sure the quoting is correct.

Comment: nope, adding `command: sh -c "pv --force -p -Ss 1024 -L 100 /dev/urandom 2>&1 > /dev/null | tr '\r' '\n'"` to my `docker-compose.yml` also outputs all the progress lines at once at the end...

Comment: hm, since I can not reproduce this I can only guess that there is some kind of output buffering is still taking place, have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe
But since `pv` should flush its output with each update it's probably buffing done by the `docker` daemon / `docker-compose`... [compose#1549](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1549) suggest to `export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`.

Comment: yes, I agree... It has to be a docker output buffering problem. The suggested `export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` sadly didn't work. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50731181/7987318) suggests using the docker `syslog` logging driver for unbuffered output as described on [docker.com/compose-file#logging](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#logging). But I can't use an external logging driver. But this may be some information that would be helpful in your answer

Comment: maybe we can find out why you get the `docker logs` output unbuffered and for me it is buffered... what host system do you use (me: Windows 10 with latest Docker Desktop)? what logging driver do you use (me: the default `json-file`)? I also tried different shells (Windows' classic cmd, git bash, WSL2)

Comment: I tested this on different Linux hosts with the default logging driver and on a Windows 10 machine with latest Docker Desktop and WSL 2 backend and it worked. I added a minimal demo app to my answer.

Comment: I just noticed that your small demo works with the `alpine` base image but not with the `ubuntu` base image... Any idea why `pv` behaves that different on the `ubuntu` base image?

Comment: I was indeed able to reproduce this with an ubuntu image. It seems for whatever reason there `tr` _does_ buffer its output. But you can disable that with `stdbuf`, see my updated answer for a minimal example of that.

Comment: yep, `stdbuf` worked for me! My full command then was `(pv --force -p "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/sql/test.sql" | mysql -uroot -proot "test") 2>&1 | stdbuf -o0 tr '\r' '\n'`. If you could add this command with the explanation of `stdbuf` to your answer I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a somewhat okayish solution:

Adding the `--numeric` flag to my `pv` command.

[From the man page of pv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv):

> -n, --numeric

> Numeric output. **Instead of giving a visual indication of progress, pv
> will give an integer percentage, one per line**, on standard error,
> suitable for piping (via convoluted redirection) into dialog(1). Note
> that -f is not required if -n is being used.

So the command in my `import.sh` would be:

```sh
pv --numeric "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/sql/test.sql" | mysql -uroot -proot "test"
```

This gives me the following output:

```
importing test.sql...
36
53
80
100
```

Since this is not as nice as the typical output of `pv` this answer is not perfect...

---

I also tried a little nicer output without the newlines like:

```
importing test.sql...
36% 53% 80% 100%
```

with appending an `awk` command:

```sh
(pv --numeric "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/sql/test.sql" | mysql -uroot -proot "test") 2>&1 | awk '{printf "%s% ",$0}'
```

But again, same problem: this did only work *inside* the container and not on the output of `docker-compose up`.