# Python 3 app running in docker-compose will not print using print('text', end='\r')

Tags: python, docker-compose

Would appreciate a suggestion for a **workaround** or **fix**:

Python 3.9 running in docker-compose 3.8 and using `CMD [ "python3", "-u", "app.py" ]`

`print('text', end='\r', flush=True)` will *not* print to terminal - want this printed.

`print('text', flush=True)` will print to terminal.

*Yes, using both `"python3", "-u"` and `flush=True` is an overkill.* ‍♂️

Comment: This might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-a-newline-or-space It seems an empty string when specifying end is sufficient.

Comment: What do you expect the `end='\r'` to do?

Comment: Using `end='\r'` you're setting cursor to start of the same line instead of moving to new line and next `stdout` value will override the previous.

Comment: Short answer: `docker-compose run app` instead of `docker-compose up`. The explanation is in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `docker-compose up` is aggregated <sup>1</sup> and effectively line-buffered <sup>2</sup> (see **Sample log**), meaning it only prints when a `\n` is seen. There are other anecdotes <sup>3,4</sup> of this behaviour with `\r`.

You can see that it is actually printed by running `docker-compose run app` <sup>5</sup>.

References:

1. https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/
2. https://eklitzke.org/stdout-buffering
3. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1549#issuecomment-745086053
4. [Output of pv on docker-compose startup not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66329515/8601760)
5. https://docs.docker.com/compose/faq/#whats-the-difference-between-up-run-and-start

## Workarounds

### 1. Run a single app directly

Run `docker-compose run app`, as mentioned above.

The output of `docker-compose run` goes directly to the stdout of your terminal.

### 2. Duplicate the output to a volume-mounted file and watch it

[`tee`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tee-invocation.html) the output in `CMD` to a file in a mounted volume and then `tail -F` that file.

```sh
touch app.log
docker-compose up & tail -F app.log
```

(Ctrl+C to exit from `tail -F app.log`.)

##### Sample files

**app.py**:

```py
from time import sleep
  
for i in range(10):
    print('text: {}'.format(i), end='\r')
    sleep(0.3)
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .
# CMD [ "python3", "-u", "app.py" ]
CMD python3 -u app.py > app.log
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
```

---

## Sample log

From `docker-compose up` without workaround:

```
==> /var/lib/docker/containers/xxx/xxx-json.log <==
{"log":"text: 0\rtext: 1\rtext: 2\rtext: 3\rtext: 4\rtext: 5\rtext: 6\rtext: 7\rtext: 8\rtext: 9\r","stream":"stdout","time":"xxx"}
```

Thus, `print('text: 0\rtext: 1\rtext: 2\rtext: 3\rtext: 4\rtext: 5\rtext: 6\rtext: 7\rtext: 8\rtext: 9\r')` effectively prints `text: 9\r`.

### How to view logs in macOS

1. Open a shell in the VM using `nc -U ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/debug-shell.sock`.
   Ref: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/release-notes/2.x/#docker-desktop-community-2400
2. Run `tail /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log`.

Answer (score 4):

The `print()` function will print all characters in your message, then append the end character after printing. If you omit `end=` it defaults to a newline character (`\n` on nix). The `\r` character moves the cursor to the beginning of the *same* line.

So lets look at a few situations in the python interpreter:

```
# print 'text' followed by \r (move to beginning of line) followed by newline
>>> print('text\r')
asdf
>>>
```

In this example, `text` is printed, the cursor then moves to the beginning of the same line, then the default newline character is printed moving to the next line. Finally, python prints its prompt.

```
# print 'text' followed by \r followed by nothing
>>> print('text', end='\r')
>>>
```

In this example, `text` is printed, the cursor moves to the beginning of the same line, then the command is finished and the interpreter prints its prompt `>>>` overwriting the `text` that was printed.

```
# print 'text followed by \r followed by nothing (alternate)
>>> print ('text\r', end='')
>>>
```

The above is identical to the previous example.

The situation is very similar when you run your script using python from the terminal, except instead of the python interpreter printing its prompt, your shell is printing its prompt after the program executes.

It's difficult to suggest a "fix" here because it's unclear what you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for these comparisons. The purpose is to run python3 in docker-compose, where python3 prints statements in terminal; specifically, when a statement is printed, the carriage is returned to the beginning of the line and, when the next statement is printed, it overwrites the previous output in the terminal. I suspect by observation that docker-compose has a bug that does not allow output of statements that include '\r'. Most likely I'll need to raise this as issue in docker's git repo.

Comment: @MatveiKruglyak Edit your question to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just need to prepend `\r`, for example:

```
import time

for i in range(10):
    print('\rcount {}'.format(i), end='')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Here you will see the message `count n`, changing every second.